# get more rows in JTable java

Tags: java, mysql, swing, user-interface

I coded Auto Suggesting Combo boxes. Functionality is,

*when a user type the first letter in either combo box  , data retrieves from the MySQL database and show in a popup list, when a user click on a suggested item ,then press Add button that item added to the J Table and clears the combo boxes

**But when I select another item from the combo box and click Add button before added one disappears**

***How can I keep Both or many items in the J Table according to above situation ***

I'll post my code:

```
private void NamecomboActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String drugname = (String) Namecombo.getSelectedItem();
    try{

    String name = "SELECT * FROM druginfo WHERE ItemName LIKE '"+drugname+"%'";

    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(name);
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()){
        IDcombo.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("ItemID"));  
    }

    }catch(Exception e){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error "+ e);
    }



}                                         

private void IDcomboActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    String drugid = (String) IDcombo.getSelectedItem();
    try{

    String name = "SELECT * FROM druginfo WHERE ItemID LIKE '"+drugid+"%'";

    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(name);
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()){
        Namecombo.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("ItemName"));  
    }

    }catch(Exception e){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error "+ e);
    }
    try{

    String exp = "SELECT ExpDate FROM druginfo WHERE ItemID LIKE '"+drugid+"%'";
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(exp);
    ResultSet rs2 = pstmt.executeQuery();

    while (rs2.next()){
        String date = rs2.getString("ExpDate");

        exptxt.setText(date);
    }

    }catch(Exception e){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error "+ e);
    }
}
```

add button action performed  for adding item to JTable;

```
private void add_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

        String temp = (String) IDcombo.getSelectedItem();
        String sql = "select ItemID,ItemName,CostPrice,InStock from druginfo where ItemID=?";
    try {   
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, temp);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        tableSale.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        IDcombo.setSelectedItem(null);
        Namecombo.setSelectedItem(null);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: The class is `JTable`. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some of your variables are correct and others are not. Be consistent and follow Java conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the current selection(resultset data) to JTable object without replacing the old data.

```
rs=pst.executeQuery();
addDataToTable(tableSale,DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
IDcombo.setSelectedItem(null);
Namecombo.setSelectedItem(null);

//ADD this method
public void addDataToTable(JTable table,TableModel model) {
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    DefaultTableModel resultSetModel = (DefaultTableModel) model;
    for (int i = 0; i < resultSetModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
        Vector row=new Vector();
        for (int j = 0; j < resultSetModel.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            row.addElement(resultSetModel.getValueAt(i, j));
        }
        tableModel.addRow(row);
    }
    tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

Comment: Selecting item doesn't come to the Jtable :( @Sarfaraz

Comment: @tenten missed fireTableDataChanged method ...updated answer try now

Comment: still not selected item come to the J table:(

Comment: put a output message in the first line and print the model object and see whats printing
`public void addDataToTable(JTable table,TableModel model) {
System.out.println(model);`

Comment: "javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel@1b85b8fa "is printing @Sarfaraz

Comment: I printed out the 'row' , It is showing wanted values(` [d00101, ALU+MAG+SIMETHI.TABS (DIOVOL) (MINT) 10T, 15.2, 100]`) but not adding to the table ... @Sarfaraz

Comment: @tenten ok let me replicate the issue.

Comment: @tenten Not sure why it's not working for you.I have replicated the things its working fine for me.

Comment: I can't find the problem :(..If I send you whole code can you check it..@Sarfaraz

Comment: @tenten Sure..send me I'll give it a try

Comment: code is too long ..how can I post it..I have no idea(I'm new here) @Sarfaraz

Comment: @tenten try posting it in pastebin or uploading in some file sharing site
http://pastebin.com/
http://www.filedropper.com/
and share it with me

Comment: @tenten can you change your set tableSale.setModel to following an try
`tableSale.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {
      {null, null, null, null}
    },
    new String [] {
      "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
    }
    ));`

Answer (score 1):

This `tableSale.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));` will replace the old model with new model.So obviously datas will be lost.You have to add values to the existing model.I have added a snippet which will help you.

Replace `tableSale.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));` with `addValuesToModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));`

```
addValuesToModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

public void addValuesToModel(TableModel resultModel) {
    DefaultTableModel tmodel = (DefaultTableModel) tableSale.getModel();
    DefaultTableModel rmodel = (DefaultTableModel) resultModel;
    for (int i = 0; i < rmodel.getRowCount(); i++) {
        Object[] row = new Object[rmodel.getColumnCount()];
        for (int j = 0; j < rmodel.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            row[j] = rmodel.getValueAt(i, j);
        }
        tmodel.addRow(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the 'resultModel' above? help me It shows an error... @Madhan

Comment: code is error free but.. catches exception when clicking add button "java.lang.ClasscastException : java.util Vector cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;"..@Madhan

Comment: select item not adding to the JTable anymore..:(:( @Madhan

Comment: what do you mean by select Item not adding to table..Can you explain more

Comment: selected item  of IDCombo is not adding anymore to the JTable by clicking add button @Madhan

Comment: I couldn't picturize what you were saying can you post a screenshot and explain

Comment: I can't post screen shots because my reputation is low :( .. I got the answer now by the another answer above :) thank you very much for the help @Madhan